# Не корректно работает примитивная загрузка файлов на php. Помогите

Tags: php, форма, upload

Такая ситуация. Делаю маме сайт и она попросила что-бы люди могли ей оставлять комментарии с выполененой роботой. Вообщем я применил самый простой способ загрузки фото и вот что получается:
При загрузке фотографий до 1мб никаких проблем. (я потвил ограничитель на 5мб)
При загрузке более 1мб скрипт который показывает загруженную картинку и заполняет INPUT названием фотографии падает в вечный лодинг хотя никак это не может происходить... А сам файл на хост загружается без проблем но не обрезается в 1024пкс, а загружается оригиналом.
Но! Если загружаем в формате PNG, а не jpg тогда всё ок.

Если при помощи телефона делать работает корректно
Еще rar загружает, как это ограничить?

Вот страница по которой можно посмотреть работу https://cats-dogs.com.ua/portfolio

Вот что в файле (https://cats-dogs.com.ua/portfolio)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        function hideBtn(){
            $('#upload').hide();
            $('#res').html("<center><div class='cssload-loader'>Идет загрузка файла</div></center>");
        }

        function handleResponse(mes) {
            $('#upload').show();
            if (mes.errors != null) {
                $('#res').html("<p>Возникли ошибки во время загрузки файла: </p>" + mes.errors);
            }   
            else {
                $('#res').html("<p>Спасибо! Фото загружено. Осталось написать и отправить комментарий :)</p><p style='text-align:left;'><img src='https://cats-dogs.com.ua/images/new/" + mes.name + "' width='220'></p><p><input type='hidden' id='img' name='img' value='" + mes.name + "' /></p>");  
                $('.img input').val(mes.name);
                $('#foto').hide();
            }   
        }

        $(function() {

$("#form").load("form-img-comm.php");

}); 

    </script>

<div id="form"></div>
 <iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px"></iframe>


<div id="res"></div>    

         <p class="img">
           <input value="" type="hidden" name="photoreport">
         </p>
```

Форма в отдельном файле:

```
<form action="uploadimgcomm.php" method="post" target="hiddenframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="hideBtn();">
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile"  />
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Загрузить"  />
</form>
```

И сам файл с загрузчиком:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    //Список разрешенных файлов
    $whitelist = array(".jpg", ".JPG", ".png");     
    $data = array();
    $error = true;

    //Проверяем разрешение файла
    foreach  ($whitelist as  $item) {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i",$_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] <= 5242880 ) $error = false;
    }




    if(!$error) { 

        $folder =  'images/';//директория в которую будет загружен файл


if($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']){


$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

        $source = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];  
        $target = $folder . $filename;

        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);



$final_width_of_image = 1024;
//$final_width_of_thumbs = 750;



    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](GIF)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($folder . $filename);
    } 

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

if ($ox > 1024) {   
    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));
}   
    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

    imagejpeg($nm, $folder . $filename);


        if($filename){




                $data = $_FILES['userfile'];
            }
            else {  
                $data['errors'] = "Во время загрузки файла произошла ошибка";
            }
        }
        else {  
            $data['errors'] = "Файл не  загружен";
        }
    }
    else{

        $data['errors'] = 'Вы загружаете запрещенный тип файла или картинка слишком большая (макс. размер 5мб)';
    }




    //Формируем js-файл    
    $res = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $res .= "var data = new Object;";
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $res .= 'data.'.$key.' = "'.$value.'";';
    }
    $res .= 'window.parent.handleResponse(data);';
    $res .= "</script>";

    echo $res;

}
else{
    die("ERROR");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная whitelist у вас бесполезна вы ее создаете но зачем не понятно раз у вас идет совсем непонятная проверка по регулярному выражению.

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](GIF)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($folder . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($folder . $filename);
    }
```

вам нужно доработать ваш whitelist примерно так

```
$whitelist = array('png', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPEG');

$FileExtension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($FileExtension, $whitelist)) {
echo "Формат файла запрещен";                
}
else
{
echo "Формат файла РАЗРЕШЕН";
// и если так то продолжаем выполнять скрипт обработки
}
```

Затем после загрузки файла на сервер обрезка размера 
на сколько я помню она делается так

**код ниже пример и требует корректировки**

с помощью Imagick

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/'$filename');

// меняем размер уже загруженной на сервер картинки
$image->resizeImage(1024, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 0.9, true);

// перезаписываем файл с новым размером
$image>writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/'$filename');
```

Проверку формата по регулярному выражению необходимо убрать.

Comment: Спасибо большое китайцу ИзКитая. Вопрос решен